# Build SDK from github repo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk

MS has upgraded bot framework sdk to v4. When using NuGet v4 is installed. They point users to a repo on Github for v3 but not sure how to install it. Any help would be appreciated.

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-v3)

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a version from NuGet?

Comment: Yeah the framework has changed drastically. Also MS themselves says to continue to use v3 for production systems... Finally, all the good reference material points to v3 and as I said they have changed the framework drastically.

Comment: Ok I found it is in the NuGet.org repo, but now I get package downgrade errors when trying to install it. Working through that now.

Comment: Ok, downgrading Microsoft.REST.client package worked. This is problem is purely a lack of understanding by a newbie.